# Joyride is working, but not calling postRideCallback

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

```
<ol data-joyride="" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;" id="tour">

<li data-id="mailbox-menu" data-button="Next" data-options="tipLocation: bottom"><h4>first</h4><div><p>xxx</p><p>yyy</p><p>zzz</p></div></li>

<li data-id="new-domain" data-button="Next" data-options="tipLocation: bottom"><h4>second</h4><div><p>aaa</p></div></li>
</ol>
```

I set a joyride up using the html above. I can call it with:

```
$(document).foundation('joyride', 'start', {
    'postRideCallback': function () {
        window.alert('hello world');
    }
})
```

and it successfully runs. However, the `postRideCallback` is never fired. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax has been updated for this, apparently in Foundation 5.

This works:

```
$(document).foundation( 
    { joyride : 
        { post_ride_callback : function() 
            { window.alert('hello world'); } 
    } 
}).foundation('joyride', 'start')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Foundation 4 just try this:

```
$(function(){ 
    $('#joyride01').foundation()
        .foundation('joyride', { 
            postRideCallback :function() { window.alert('hello world'); // or whatever you want to call
        }
    });
 });
```

That's going to work fine.

I hope I helped you! =D

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Joyride pluggin and I use this, I hope it helps :

```
        $(window).load(function () {
        $('#joyRideTipContent').joyride({
            'tipLocation': 'top',
            autoStart: true,
            postRideCallback: function () {
                PromptDisableTutorial();
            },
            modal: false,
            expose: true
        });
    });
```